# Using camera with Mac Catalyst

Tags: ios, uikit, uikitformac

In an app ported to Mac Catalyst, the camera interface always turned out to be blank.

I have checked: the capabilities includes "Camera", the privacy setting in info.plist is there (the iPad app shows the camera fine), and I even try to include front camera for UIImagePickerController.

```
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.cameraDevice = .front   // added for Mac
        self.present(imagePicker, animated:true, completion:nil)            
    }
```

The error I got is: "[Generic] Could not create video device input: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11814"

Answer (score 0):

I have the same mistake, I'm afraid it's a bug ...
Everything works correctly on iOS and iPadOS.
For the moment I think there's no way to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

You need [Requesting Authorization for Media Capture on macOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_macos)

```
import AVFoundation

AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { granted in
     let ctrl = UIImagePickerController()
     ctrl.sourceType = .camera
     self.present(ctrl, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Add to `info.plist`

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>  .... </string>
```